Zip two lists into a struct in polars
How to achieve this zip operation in pure polars form, I have two lists, and want to map first element of first list to first element of second list, second element of first list to second element of second list and so on.
import polars as pl


df = pl.DataFrame({
    "first_name": [["John", "Jane", "Alice"]],
    "score": [[70, 80, 90]]
})

df = df.with_columns(l=pl.struct(cs.all()).map_elements(lambda row: dict(zip(row['first_name'], row['score']))))


>>> df.select(pl.col.first_name.explode(), pl.col.score.explode())
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ first_name ┆ score │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str        ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ John       ┆ 70    │
│ Jane       ┆ 80    │
│ Alice      ┆ 90    │
└────────────┴───────┘


Do an explode on multiple columns at once:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"first_name": [["John", "Jane", "Alice"]], "score": [[70, 80, 90]]})

print(df.explode("first_name", "score"))

Output:
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ first_name ┆ score │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str        ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ John       ┆ 70    │
│ Jane       ┆ 80    │
│ Alice      ┆ 90    │
└────────────┴───────┘

